# Cannot delete Notification on Android < 5.0

Tags: android, notifications

I create Notifications. For that i use the following `Service`:

```
public class NFCUploadService extends Service implements MeasureDataPostCallback {
    private static final int IMAGE_SEND_NFC_SERVICE_ID = 100;
    private SessionLastMeasureDataPreferences sessionLastMeasureDataPreferences = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        this.sessionLastMeasureDataPreferences = new SessionLastMeasureDataPreferences(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().invalidateInstance();

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_EMAIL) != null) {
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setEmail(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_EMAIL));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setPassword(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_PASSWORD));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setYear(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_YEAR));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setMonth(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MONTH));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setDay(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_DAY));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setHour(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_HOUR));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setMinute(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MINUTE));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setValue(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_VALUE));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setMealTime(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MEALTIME));
            SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setMood(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MOOD));

            if(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_FILE_PATH) != null) {
                SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setImageFile(new File(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_FILE_PATH)));
            } else {
                SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().setImageFile(null);
            }
        } 

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ForegroundServiceTags.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION.getValue()) || intent.getAction().equals(ForegroundServiceTags.REPEAT_ACTION.getValue())) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MeasureDataFragment.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(ForegroundServiceTags.MAIN_ACTION.getValue());
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            style.addLine(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_email) + ": " + SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getEmail());
            style.addLine(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_date) + ": " + Helper.getDateTimePattern(SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getDay(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getMonth(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getYear(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getHour(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getMinute()));
            style.addLine(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_measure_value) + ": " + SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getValue());

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_measuredata_transfer));
            builder.setTicker(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_measuredata_transfer_new));
            builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.setStyle(style);
            Notification notification = builder.build();

            this.startForeground(IMAGE_SEND_NFC_SERVICE_ID, notification);
            this.startTask(SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getEmail(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getPassword(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getYear(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getMonth(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getDay(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getHour(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getMinute(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getValue(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getMealTime(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getMood(), SessionNFCUploadService.getInstance().getImageFile());
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ForegroundServiceTags.CANCEL_ACTION.getValue())) {
            this.stopForeground(true);
            this.stopSelf();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ForegroundServiceTags.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION.getValue())) {
            this.stopForeground(true);
            this.stopSelf();
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasureDataPostCompleted(StatusMeasureDataPost status, MeasureDataPostPOJO measureDataPostPOJO) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MeasureDataFragment.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(ForegroundServiceTags.MAIN_ACTION.getValue());
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent repeatIntent = new Intent(this, NFCUploadService.class);
        repeatIntent.setAction(ForegroundServiceTags.REPEAT_ACTION.getValue());

        PendingIntent pendingRepeatIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, repeatIntent, 0);

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(this, NFCUploadService.class);
        cancelIntent.setAction(ForegroundServiceTags.CANCEL_ACTION.getValue());

        PendingIntent pendingCancelIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, cancelIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_measuredata_transfer));
        builder.setTicker(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_measuredata_transfer_new));
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        switch(status) {
        case ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_connection_failed));
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_repeat), pendingRepeatIntent);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_cancel), pendingCancelIntent);
            break;
        case ERROR_DB_CONNECTION_FAILED:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_db_connection_failed));
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_repeat), pendingRepeatIntent);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_cancel), pendingCancelIntent);
            break;
        case ERROR_IO_EXCEPTION:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_io_exception));
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_repeat), pendingRepeatIntent);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_cancel), pendingCancelIntent);
            break;
        case ERROR_JSON_EXCEPTION:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_json_exception));
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_repeat), pendingRepeatIntent);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_cancel), pendingCancelIntent);
            break;
        case ERROR_PROTOCOL_EXCEPTION:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_protocol_exception));
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_repeat), pendingRepeatIntent);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_cancel), pendingCancelIntent);
            break;
        case ERROR_WRONG_PARAMETERS:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_wrong_parameters));
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_repeat), pendingRepeatIntent);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_cancel), pendingCancelIntent);
            break;
        case ERROR_MEASUREDATA_ALREADY_EXISTS:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_measuredata_already_exists));

            this.stopForeground(false);
            break;
        case MEASUREDATA_TRANSFERED:
            builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_data_saved));

            String email = measureDataPostPOJO.getUser().getEmail();

            MeasureDataListEntry measureData = this.sessionLastMeasureDataPreferences.getMeasureData(email);
            MeasureDataListEntry measureDataListEntry = new MeasureDataListEntry();

            measureDataListEntry.setValue(measureDataPostPOJO.getUser().getValue());
            measureDataListEntry.setTime(measureDataPostPOJO.getUser().getTime());

            if(measureData.compareTo(measureDataListEntry) > 0) {
                this.sessionLastMeasureDataPreferences.setMeasureData(email, measureDataListEntry);
            }

            this.stopForeground(false);
            break;
        }

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(IMAGE_SEND_NFC_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    private void startTask(String email, String password, String year, String month, String day, String hour, String minute, String value, String mealTime, String mood, File imageFile) {
        MeasureDataPostTask task = new MeasureDataPostTask(email, password, year, month, day, hour, minute, value, mealTime, mood, imageFile);
        task.setCallback(this);
        task.execute(this);
    }
}
```

Until now i just tested devices with android version 5.0 and greater and everything is working fine. When a Notification pops up i can just swipe it away to delete it.

However... i cant delete those Notifications on a Galaxy Ace device with Android 4.4.2. It is also not working on a Samsung Active Tab with Android 4.4.4. There is no button to delete the Notification and also the swipe to delete is not working. To delete the Notification i need to kill the App.

Does someone know why it isnt working on android versions < 5.0 and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `setOngoing(true)`. With that call, you are saying that you do not want the `Notification` to be able to be cleared.

Comment: Cant be right because i can clear the notifications on android >= 5.0. When i set ongoing to false the notification is automatically disapearing and i really dont want that.

Comment: @Mulgard: "Cant be right because i can clear the notifications on android >= 5.0" -- you can't clear a `setOngoing()` notification on any version of Android, outside of device bugs. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Progress) demonstrates this, as you cannot swipe off the notification until after the progress is done. I just tested it on a Nexus 4 and a Nexus 5 (5.1), and `setOngoing()` works as documented and as I describe.

Comment: But thats really weird because i also have a nexus 4 with android 5.0.2, a galaxy tab s with android 5.1 and a samsung galaxy s6 with android 5.1. on all devices i can just swipe away the notifications with the code i posted above.

Comment: @Mulgard: Try the sample that I linked to. If you get the same results as I do, then there's something else in the configuration of your `Notification` that is giving you the unexpected Android 5.x results.